# How to set the position of a sprite to the center of the screen

Tags: c++, sfml

I have some code on a pong game i've been working on:
The code sample shows that when the ball hits the bottom of the window, the ball resets to the middle of the window. What I'm trying to achieve is that I'd like to be able to add some code so that if the ball hits the top of the window, the ball will reset back to the middle.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
//...

// IF BALL GETS PAST PLAYER PADDLE AND TOUCHES BOTTOM OF SCREEN
if (GetPosition().y - GetHeight()/2 <= 0)
{
    _angle = 180 - _angle;
    moveByY = -moveByY;
}

if (GetPosition().y + GetHeight()/2 + moveByY >= Game::SCREEN_HEIGHT)
{
    // RESET BALL TO MIDDLE OF SCREEN AND RESET TIMER TO 0
    GetSprite().SetPosition(Game::SCREEN_WIDTH/2, Game::SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);
    _angle = (float)sf::Randomizer::Random(0,360);
    _velocity = 220.0f;
    _elapsedTimeSinceStart = 0.0f;
}

//...
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my pong game is vertical, the opponent paddle is at the top of the window and the player paddle is at the bottom of the window

Comment: I figured this out, just copied the code again and removed the lines that rebounded the ball back. I'm now working to setting up the boundary so that the paddle doesn't continue to move beyond the window boundary...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand clearly the problem here, where exactly is the problem and what is it doing right now that you don't want it to do?

Comment: @user1283674 not directly related to the question but you should consider upgrading your version of SFML from 1.x to 2.1. SFML 1.x is not maintained anymore, and somewhat buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, added some more conditional statements to check the boundary, if the ball hits the top then reset the ball to the middle of the screen.

Comment: There should be a check next to your answer - you can mark it as answered then.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to do that - Thank you